# What's faster: left join on NVL(key,'~') = otherkey or key = otherkey where is not null (or maybe inner query?)

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

I'm trying to align historical source tables to a daily snapshot for a new Dimension table.
I finally got my query to do what I want but I'm struggling with performance tuning between two equivalent versions. I'm on a Dev environment with no access to Prod so my tests are not realistic (results are immediate). The prod environment will have many millions of lines and dozens of columns with multiple historical versions of each field, so performance is important. Performance will be reveiwed by a DBA of course, but this will take some time and I'd like to understand what happens under the hood.

For the code below, notice A, B, C & X share a key, X has a subset of the key only (left join needed) and Y has the descriptive information for X (and doesn't have the main key).

My query runs something like this:

```
    Select 
      A.field,
      B.field,
      C.field,
      nvl(X.field,valueIfNull),    --nvl is the oracle equivalent of coalesce
      nvl(Y.field,valueIfNull)
    from tableA A
      inner join tables BCD B, C, D
        on A.key = B.key 
        and A.date<= B.date < A.date

    ... do this 3 times for B, C & D...
```

Now here I have two options that I see (and that work)

```
       left join tableX X
         on A.key = X.key and A.date = X.date -- this will yield null values -> left join -> ok
       left join tableY Y
         on Y.key = nvl(**X**.key,'~') and Y.date = X.date
       where Y.status in ('statusFlag1');
```

Alternatively, this works too:

```
        left join tableX X
         on A.key = X.key and A.date = X.date -- this will yield null values -> left join -> ok
       left join tableY Y
         on Y.key = X.key and Y.date = X.date
       where (Y.status in ('statusFlag1') or Y.status is null);
```

A last alternative would be to use an inner query to compute the Y & X columns and join that one. I haven't added it yet because it would be less readable imo, but I could if it will mean performance improvement.

So basically is it faster to nvl and join on those "null" values, or to add the nulls in the where clause? Or use an inner query? We will have many millions of lines, mi

Comment: As mentioned in the question, because I don't have access to production and my test data is a very small subset, in which both the queries give the exact same performance

Comment: @DawTheDataDawer . . . I don't think these are equivalent.  It is hard to see what you really want, but you should choose the correct logic.

Comment: Yes, Martin schapendonk made it clear in the answer below that my case is not transposable to a simple quivalent. I will use the most generally applicable logic (without nvl) and wait for the BDA's to validate the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both solutions would require the `or Y.status is null` because the left join can give no results for Y in both cases (or you would change the query result).

With that added, it is better to do the join directly on the keys without using nvl() as that is a heavy operation for the database.

Real life performance should still be measured on production as hardware, indexes, table size (also relatively to each other) and database parameters have a lot of influence.

Comment: If "~" is a valid key in Y and you are relating records of X with an unrelated record of Y that coincidentally happens to have status you are not interested in, your outcome is more luck then wisdom. Please do not do that.

Comment: Thanks! Noted for performance, I'll go with the where clause. Conserning the Null in both cases, this is not true in my model because the Y.status is only null as a result of the left join, it's a non nullable value that has the '~' in the keyfield, therefore nvl(X.keyfield, '~') yields complete results, because x.key is only nulled as a result of the first left join. As MT0 pointed out, the second join is actually an inner join

Comment: Actually, yes and no. It's a null replacement, meaning it will always have status flag1. In 100% of the cases where the keys are "~", the values are default. Of course what you say is correct and I will not join on "~" anymore as it is dangerous. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```sql
left join tableX X
  on A.key = X.key and A.date = X.date -- this will yield null values -> left join -> ok
left join tableY Y
  on Y.key = nvl(**X**.key,'~') and Y.date = X.date
where Y.status in ('statusFlag1');
```

This is not a `LEFT JOIN` as the `WHERE` clause enforces that there must be a value in `Y.status` and so this is effectively an `INNER JOIN` as, since `Y.status` cannot be `NULL`; then assuming `Y.date` is `NOT NULL` then `X.date` also cannot be `NULL` so `X` must be a valid row too.

If you want a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` then put the filter condition in the `ON` clause and not in the `WHERE` clause:

```sql
left join tableX X
  on ( A.key = X.key and A.date = X.date )
left join tableY Y
  on ( Y.key = X.key and Y.date = X.date AND Y.status = 'statusFlag1' );
```

Alternatively, if you only want the combination of X and Y tables where `Y.status` has the desired flag then use a sub-query:

```sql
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT x.*,
         y.*
  FROM   tableX X
         INNER JOIN tableY Y
         ON (Y.key = X.key and Y.date = X.date)
  WHERE  Y.status = 'statusFlag1'
) XY
  on ( A.key = XY.key and A.date = XY.date );
```

*Note: This does not address performance as that is something you will have to profile with your tables, partitions, indexes, data, statistics and hardware and is not something the we can easily advise on.*

Comment: This is entirely correct! The left join is only needed on the A -> X join, because each value in X has a values in Y! Thanks a bunch! And pity for perf, I'll need to wait for the DBA